# Explanation about getSelect() join() joinLeft()

Tags: magento-1.9, database, query

I don't understand these functions of Magento 1:

> - getSelect()
> - join()
> - joinLeft()

Where can I find a complete doc with all functions documentation ?

Thanks..

Comment: is this question about magento 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The All Explanation i am Providing is On the Basis Of Magento2 the
>   same will be in magento1 with some Syntax differences

You can use These Functions to Add Filters On your Database Collection

In your

> Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\ModuleName\Collection

Like

**getSelect()**

```
/**
     * Get All Pages Have status Active
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function addFilterToStatus($status=1)
    {
        $this->getSelect()
            ->where('main_table.page_status = '.$status.' ');
        return $this;
    }
```

**join()**

```
   /**
     * Get Collection of Specfic Customer Groups
     * @param Integer
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function addFilterToCustomer($cusGroupId)
    {
        $this->getSelect()
            ->join(
                ['customer_groups' => $this->getTable('joined_table_name')], 'main_table.page_id = customer_groups.page_id', []
            )->where('customer_groups.customer_group_id = (?)', $cusGroupId);

        return $this;

    }
```

In the same way You can use Left Join as Well